# How To Install PECL YAML Extension on Mac?

Tags: php, parsing, yaml, pecl, libyaml

My goals is to be able to use the PHP functions for parsing YAML detailed in the PHP docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.yaml.php

To install the PECL yaml extension I've opened Terminal and typed:

```
brew install libyaml
```

Then

```
sudo /usr/local/php5/bin/pecl install pecl_http
```

Then

```
sudo /usr/local/php5/bin/pecl install yaml
```

But I think it fails to install the PECL yaml extension. It says:

```
3 warnings and 16 errors generated.
make: *** [yaml.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

And when I try to use `yaml_parse_file()` in my program, it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file()
```

How do I properly install the PECL yaml extension so I can use the PHP functions for parsing YAML?

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: How do I properly install the PECL yaml extension so I can use the PHP functions for parsing YAML?

Comment: Well, your first step will be to figure out what those 16 errors were that you mention. They probably scrolled past on the screen somewhere.

Comment: try to `brew install php55-yaml`, or whatever version of php you have (is available for 5.5,5.6,7.0,7.1)

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue and below steps helped me.

First be sure you have installed yaml extension (as I know since brew will not help us for packages so better to use pecl)

Even though some errors (such as failed for mkdir) occurred during installation it was completed.

```
pecl install yaml
```

Next open your php.ini file and add this line according to your path to yaml.so file.

```
extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php70-yaml/2.0.0/yaml.so
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: After my upgrade to php 7.4, ext-yaml was installed, but somehow not working. Out of laziness I simply did `pecl uninstall yaml`and then again `pecl install yaml`- worked well ;).